# Why can't we increase diameter of induction motors as we can do in axial flux motors?

Tags: induction-motor, electric-machine

Axial flux motors have high torque to weight ratio. One of the reason is that it has larger diameter. which means since T=F*r . if r-->radius increases torque increases. More specifically I read it to be called the lever concept.
This same concept why can't we apply in induction motors? Just increase the diameter and we can get a boast in torque.

Answer (score 1):

Torque is not the most important, efficiency, power to weight ratio are.

But the mains concern would be the moment of inertia. When you start the IM, the rotor is standstill and the current is enormous. With a small inertia rotor, it accelerate fast and the start time is shorter.

But we could use VFD. You would require a large capacitor bank to store the regenerative energy, so again not economic.